Find all non-negative integers $x^2+3y^2=z^2,\mathrm{gcd}(x,y)=1,x,y,z>0.$
I use geometric methods to get the parametric form$\;x=p^2-3q^2,y=2pq,z=p^2+3q^2,\mathrm{gcd}(p,q)=1$, but it doesn't include the solution (1,1,2).
The process is as follows:
Elliptic equations  $x^2+3y^2=1$Crossing point$A(-1,0)$,let $m\in Q$be the slope of$ L:y=m(x+1)$.Substitute $L$ into the elliptic equation and find the coordinates of the other point :
$$(1+3m^2)x^2+6m^2x+3m^2-1=0$$
The root formula gives $x=\frac{1-3m^2}{1+3m^2}$,so $y=\frac{2m}{1+3m^2}$.Let $m=\frac{q}{p},\mathrm{gcd}(p,q)=1$get
$$x=\frac{p^2-3q^2}{p^2+3q^2},y=\frac{2pq}{p^2+3q^2}.$$
Removing the denominator yields  integer solutions  to the equation the equation $x^2+3y^2=z^2$,
$$x=p^2-3q^2,y=2pq,z=p^2+3q^2,\mathrm{gcd}(p,q)=1.$$

Could you go into more detail about your geometric method? That should have worked, so I'm sure you've just made a calculation mistake somewhere.

The solutions are well known, see for example this duplicate.

I would start by $3y^2=z^2-x^2=(z-x) \cdot (z+x)$ and start playing around with divisibility by $3$.

Before Asking any questions search it in Approach zero website https://approach0.xyz/search/

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2155294/1296310

@Christopher Wells,Thank you, now I have written the process, please give me some guidiance.

@Dominique：Thank you for your help. I have understood your method. Now I would like to know why the geometric method cannot succeed.

Stereographic projection around one solution does give all rational solutions, your common denominator is $p^2 + 3 q^2$    Take your expressions $x=p^2-3q^2,y=2pq,z=p^2+3q^2,\mathrm{gcd}(p,q)=1$   and calculate $g = \gcd(x,y,z).$  Then accepting $(x/g, y/g, z/g)$ really does give all integer solutions.  If you take $p=3, q=1$ you start with $(6,6,12)$  with gcd 6. Divide out to get the desired $(1,1,2)$

In order to get all integer solutions, it is usually necessary to use more than one parametrization of Pythagorean Triple sort.  Using letters u,v, the other recipe is $ x = 2 u^2 + 2uv - v^2, ; ; y = 2 uv + v^2, ; ; z = 2 u^2 + 2uv + 2v^2. $  As in your original, you are free to take absolute values if $x,y,z$   turn out negative.. So $u=0, v=1$ gives  $(-1,2, 2)$

mistype, $(-1,1,2)$  with absolute values becomes $(1,1,2)$

@Will Jagy：Thank you very much. I solved my problem. For your second method, how do you get these recipe?Could you go into more detail about the second method?

First thing, it is a theorem in Mordell, Diophantine Equations that the (integer) null set of an indefinite ternary quadratic can be parametrized by a finite number  of recipes of Pythagorean Triple type.  Let me put that at the end, page 47.
Finding these comes from one initial recipe, your $p^2 - 3 q^2, 2pq, p^2 + 3 q^2,$  and examining what happens when the greatest common divisor of the three  is larger than one;  that is, when not coprime, despite $\gcd(p,q) = 1.$ The common divisor $g$  divides the "discriminant" of the ternary form, which is $-12$   as I calculate such things. The possible prime $g$ are $2,3$
If $p,q$   are both odd, we see that the gcd is even, actually $2$   as $2pq \equiv 2 \pmod 4.$ Note, we consider $3$  or $6$ separately.  Since $p,q$ are congruent $\pmod 2$ we can write  $p = r+s$ and $q = r-s.$   Write out your three elements, divide each by $2,$   you get
$$ -r^2 + 4 r s - s^2 \; , \; \; \; r^2 - s^2 \; , \; \;  2r^2 - 2 rs + 2 s^2 \; \; . \; \;  $$
In my earlier comments, I took a different path for this, arriving at a triple of "equivalent"  binary forms. That is, still binary discriminants $ 12, 4, -12.$  There is a fair amount of freedom in making choices here.
To return from this triple to the triple in earlier comments  is
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
-1 & 4 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0 & -1 \\ 
2 & -2 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 2 & -1 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
The matrix in the middle is of a special pattern, for some  integers $a,b,c,d$  with $ad - bc = \pm 1, $
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
a^2 & 2ab & b^2 \\ 
ac & ad+bc & bd \\ 
c^2 & 2cd & d^2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
This time $a=b=c=1$ and $d=0$
Various places to see this special matrix. Page 23, formula (1.54) in Magnus (1974) Noneuclidean Tessellations and Their Groups. Page 301, formula (5.6)  in Cassels (1978), Rational Quadratic Forms.  Page 451, formula (3) in Fricke and Klein (1897) Vorlesungen uber der Theorie der Automorphen Functionen; erster Band, die gruppentheoretischen Grundlagen. Also page 369, formula (3) in the English translation, (2017) by Arthur M. DuPre, proofread by Patrick Boland. They gave the title  Lectures on the Theory of Automorphic Functions; First Volume. They left out the  subtitle "group theory fundamentals."

